# Flash audio player that can play binary audio streams

Tags: flash, audio, audio-streaming

My server is streaming binary audio data (mostly mp3 files) to a client (a browser). This client stores the audio data in memory.

What I'm looking for is a flash audio player that I can input the binary audio data so that it can play the audio file.

Preferably, the flash client is merely a bridge to Javascript so that I can handle everything in Javascript and simply use Flash's audio features, but this is not a requirement.

Does such audio player exist?

Comment: Tom,
Were you able to figure this out? I have a similar requirement, and i am looking for answer.

Comment: @user815357, unfortunately I did not.

Comment: @user815357, you could request a bounty if you wish ;)

Answer (score 0):

Currently I do not know of any service that offers what you are seeking (and I'm not quite sure how it would be possible). However, here is another option for you:

Use a service like [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org) to play the audio for you. Once you know how to use Flowplayer, you have another choice to make. You can either

1. Have a PHP or ASP page where the user uploads a file (temporarily) to your server and then you have Flowplayer load it (this is like the example below). Or,
2. You can use the `file://` or `data:` protocols to avoid server side scripting. The problem with using the `file://` or `data:` protocols is that it won't be cross browser.

If you are going to try the server side method (recommended for cross-browser functionality) then [here is an example I am working on.](http://cmon.horizon-host.com/player/) In this example, you pick a file and it is then uploaded to the server. After that is done, I have Flowplayer load the file and that's all there is to it.

By the way Flowplayer was built more as a movie player so you can check out [this](http://flash-mp3-player.net/players/mini/documentation/) mp3 flash player. Same concept as Flowplayer for this, upload the temporary file and then have this service play the file.

**The problem with you are trying to do is that you can't give a large amount of input to a flash file. This is because to give input, you would link to something like`mp3player.swf?file=file.mp3`. This tells the flash file what to do. You can't give this binary input (even base64) because there is a limit on url length.**